# Multiple Variables in config.yml

Tags: java, bukkit

So i am having a clue on how to like make it so Multiple Varables from a config.yml will be split into each.

What i am trying to describe is like say i got this:

`MODS: Durgal, Wolfy, Pat`

I would like if it checks the config.yml, and sees that Wolfy is a mod and then does what ever the code i want.

BTW I'm new to Bukkit and i am just starting with a random project i know some stuff but i am just stuck here and have been trying for like a hour and researching what to do but i still don't know what to do.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "Multiple Variables from a config.yml will be split into each"?

Comment: @jthort What i kinda want is like i have a config and it looks like say `Mods: WolfyCodes, Durgs, Pat` and than it would take those 3 usernames and split them and put 1 of the 3 usernames into this code `Player playerrr = Bukkit.getPlayer("WolfyCodes");` Where it says WolfyCodes i want it to have the config usernames.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple variables as you made your configs, and then split them up using Strings.

config.yml:

> MODS: "Durgal,Wolfy,Pat"

Your Plugin:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
    String allMods = config.getString("MODS");
    String[] modsList = allMods.split(",");
}
```

---

Or you can have a StringList in your config.yml

config.yml:

[image]

And retrieve it as such:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
    List<String> mods = config.getStringList("mods");
    for (String moderator : mods) {
        Player mod = Bukkit.getPlayer(moderador);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just one more question... How would i add another username to that, im probably going to use the second one.

Comment: You can keep adding to that list, I editted the question.